# How to align links

Tags: html, css

Example of what i want to accomplish: http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfwd/ch09/#

As you can see they place the "RPM Music" to the left and the Links to the right
and they both align perfectly, But everytime i try to do the same my links always end up
on the bottom right or do something els weird. Also they are using a Blueprint.css and i don't want to use none of that can someone please give me some tips.

Comment: Show your markup at least, and what css youve tried?

Comment: create a jsfiddle please

Comment: In order for us to help you, you should add something you've tried already, also provide us with what you already have using a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXRh7/ As you can see i keep geting the same result, my link at the bottom-right and my logo top-left. and i want my links to be align with my logo. Help a noob out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the inelegant way would be something like:

```
div.wrapper {
 float: left;
 some styles
}

div.linkWrap {
float: left;
some other styles
}


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image">img</div>
    <div class ="linkWrap">
        <div class="link"><a href="">some link</a></div>
        <div class="linkBody">some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```